# create CSS grid without writing a div for each cell

Tags: html, css

I need a grid with 100 cells for a battleship game I'm making (using html, css, and JavaScript), but I don't want to create 100 divs in html to make it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
  <div class="item-3"></div>
  <div class="item-4"></div>
  <div class="item-5"></div>
  <div class="item-6"></div>
  ...
</div>
```

Is there way were I can avoid this and then just access them by parent in css?

```
.cell:nth-child(n) {
  //code
}
```

I know a way where I can work around this without using a grid, but this seems the most simple way if I can just get past this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not exactly the way you want to solve this but you could use JS to generate your DIVs yielding an ugly HTML structure being displayed but small and clean Source Code regarding HTML and JS.

Comment: do you need rows of a certain number of columns? What would that number be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can programmatically create them using Javascript:

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container')

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var el = document.createElement('div')
  el.classList.add('item-' + (i + 1))
  container.appendChild(el)
}

console.log(container.children.length) // 100
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

If you inspect by pressing <kbd>Cmd/Ctrl+Shift+C</kbd> in Chrome, you can see that there are a hundred `div`s.

Each of them has a `class` attribute that equals `item-n`, where `n` is a number between `1` and `100`.

Answer (score 1):

I thought you might need some CSS as well? I used @GalaxyCat105's script (above) and added some grid-style magic.

```js
var container = document.querySelector('.container')

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
var el = document.createElement('div')
el.classList.add('item-' + (i + 1))
container.appendChild(el)
}

console.log(container.children.length) // 100
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito+Sans:400,700|Cormorant+Garamond:300,700|Titillium+Web:200,200i,400,400i,700|Orbitron:700&display=swap');

:root {
    --color-woodsmoke:      #161B1E;
    --color-boulder:        #767676;
    --color-gallery:        #F0F0F0;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: var(--color-woodsmoke);
    margin: 0;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-align: center;
}

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(280px, 1fr));
    gap: .5em;
    padding: 1em;
}

[class^="item"] {
    min-height: 10em;
    background: var(--color-gallery);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-boulder);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.04);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>100 Items</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>One hundred items</h1>
    <div class="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```